# Protecting Workbook in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I try to protect an Excel workbook with openpyxl.

So far I had a look into the different, potentially relevant classes but I can't find a `set_password` method like the one for [worksheets](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.protection.html#openpyxl.worksheet.protection.SheetProtection.set_password).

There happens to be the [workbook.protection](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.workbook.protection.html#openpyxl.workbook.protection.WorkbookProtection) module that I tried my luck with. My code, boiled down to the absolute relevant minimum is as follows:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.workbook.protection import WorkbookProtection

wb = Workbook()
wb.security = WorkbookProtection(workbookPassword='0000', revisionsPassword = '0000', lockWindows = True, lockStructure = True, lockRevision = True)
wb.create_sheet("testSheet")
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

I don't get any errors but no protection either. Any help would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: the only protection i could found is on worksheet, with `wb["testSheet"].protection.set_password('test')`, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122496/password-protecting-excel-file-using-python).

Comment: would using `load_workbook(file, read_only=True).get_sheet_names()` to create a list, and then loop through protecting each sheet work?

Comment: @PRMoureu yes, as I said, I am aware of this but can't find a similar method for workbooks.

Comment: @MattR protecting each sheet is something different than protecting the workbook. In a protected sheet the cells are protected from editing but the worksheet itself can still be edited. In a protected workbook the sheet could not be edited (eg renamed).

Comment: from the source, it seems the worksheet is not protected by default, have you try to override this parameter by creating a protection like you did with Workbook and give `sheet=False` or even other elements?

Comment: This doesn't currently work in Openpyxl (v2.4.8) - the password is not written to the output file. I'm working on a PR for this (https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/180/read-and-write-workbook-protection/diff), so hopefully it will be included in future releases.

Comment: @gar thank you for your response. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It appears you were satisfied with the answer from @gar but in case other visitors to this question are actually looking for a way to prevent the workbook from being opened at all without the password, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245208/add-a-password-unattended-to-existing-xlsx-without-windows-exclusive-tools) is more relevant.

Comment: Any  idea when it  comes to locking all columns except  one , from being copied, as opposed to just locking at workbook level? I'm able to lock the worksheet but  still one can Select all cells, copy and paste values in a new sheet. That exposes  hidden columns  etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't currently work in Openpyxl (v2.4.8) - the password is not written to the output file. There is an open PR for this (https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-requests/180/read-and-write-workbook-protection/diff), so hopefully it will be included in future releases.