# Set Password for excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am trying to set password for excel file generated using openpyxl. I went through **openpyxl**. Openpyxl has a workbook protection functionality, but it does not support whole workbook lock using password as it does in MS Excel. I also looked into **xlsxwriter**, **xlrd**, **xlwt**.

Is there any way in python which i can set password for an excel file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try here.. Think this answers your question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122496/password-protecting-excel-file-using-python)

Comment: I have seen this link, Openpyxl has no functionality to password protect a workbook. but that question does not provide a clear answer whether any python library other than Openpyxl can be used to lock an excel file or whole excel workbook.

Comment: it kind of does, basically i get the impression that you cant do it, check out this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220389/protecting-workbook-in-openpyxl?noredirect=1&lq=1)  If you follow @gar link to the bitbucket page you mind find some more help there.

Comment: @amyoakes - That did get implemented, but it still doesn't provide the functionality that I think Sanjo meant, which is to make it so that the workbook *cannot even be opened* without the password. The feature that got implemented was protection of the workbook *structure*, which simply means you cannot add, move, delete, hide, or unhide sheets (without disabling the protection, which is rather easy to do). You can still open the workbook normally.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282875/95852) on a similar (or perhaps duplicate) question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using the below code,

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

ws=wb.worksheets[0]
ws.protection.set_password('test')
wb.save('sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: Unfortunately code you mentioned only provide worksheet protection for the selected worksheet, not for the whole workbook or excel file in Openpyxl.

Comment: Can you try changing the index of worksheets

Comment: please test your code before answer

Comment: don't think the password protection work.