# Set password for xlsx file by Python xlsxwirter package

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am trying to set password for xlsx file. I use xlsxwriter to package for now to generate the csv file. However, didn't reach any information to set password for the csv file.

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918949/set-password-for-excel-file-using-python). But the openpyxl isn't the package I  might gonna to use.

Do anyone know hot to simply set password for xlsx file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

CSV files are plain text - there's no such thing as adding a password.

openpyxl is a package to handle *excel* files - which aren't csv, so it's not relevant