# Is there a solution for: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'workbookPassword'

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am automating creation of business reports via Excel. I have achieved all I wanted to with the exception of password protecting the workbook which continues to fail. Is there a bug in Python 3.7.3 or openpyxl 2.6.2?

I checked the versions of openpyxl and Python and tried various different code to get this working with no luck.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test1.xlsx' )

wb.security.workbookPassword.value = 'test_password'
wb.security.lockStructure = True
```

The expected result is to have the workbook prompt for a password when a user opens it. The results I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'workbookPassword'.
```

One post states "Your solution is then to create a default `WorkbookProtection()`, assign it to the workbook, and then set the workbook password" but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: It looks like `wb.security` doesn't return anything.  If you `print(wb.__dict__)` I am guessing you won't see any `security` attribute. If I had to guess its because there is no `security` which is why the solution you read said you need to make a default.

Comment: `wb.security = WorkbookProtection()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protecting Workbook in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220389/protecting-workbook-in-openpyxl)

Comment: Yes, print(wb.__dict__) shows 'security': none. wb.security = WorkbookProtection() results in NameError: name 'WorkbookProtection' is not defined. Still struggling here. I am a novice at this so any additional help appreciated.

Comment: @TimC: Your attemp is slightly different from the docs [Workbook Protection](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html#workbook-protection) but this [issue on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1261/protection-of-the-protected-sheet-is) seems relevant to you.