# How to add password to a csv/excel created with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, encryption

have dataframe how to encrypt it with a password

```
import pandas as pd 
  
# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
  
# Creating DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

are there any pandas options to add  a password  excel or csv which is created with data frame.

So that a password is required to open that csv or excel with GUI.

Tried this:

```
df.to_excel('123.xlsx')

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

test_spreadsheet = "123.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(test_spreadsheet)
wb.security.workbookPassword = "password"
```

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

test_spreadsheet = "123.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(test_spreadsheet)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.protection
ws.protection.set_password('test')
wb.save('12344.xlsx')
```

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = '123.xlsx')

wb.security.workbookPassword = 'test'
wb.security.lockStructure = True

wb.save('123_password.xlsx')
```

```
wb = Workbook('123.xlsx') 
ws = wb.worksheets[0] 
ws.protect('abc123.xlsx')
```

But when i open it. the file is opening without any prompt of password . tried in google sheets and libre office

Found out that : Openpyxl's WorkbookProtection only works for preventing modifying sheets that are there.

os: Linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password Protecting Excel file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122496/password-protecting-excel-file-using-python)

Comment: No tried all those ways. please check the codes i provided which i tried

Comment: @Recursing How can we run  csscript.exe in linux ?

Comment: Have you looked into `xlsxwriter`?

Comment: @S3DEV tried this `wb = Workbook('123.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.protect('abc123.xlsx')`   getting `list index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import os
import win32com.client as w32

def encrypt_xlsx(path, password):
    xl = w32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    path = path if os.path.isabs(path) else os.path.abspath(path)
    
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(path)
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs(path, 51, password)
    xl.Quit()
```

Include the import statements and also the `encrypt_xlsx` function.
Next, call the function with the `path` and `password`.

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4]}); df.to_excel('123.xlsx')
>>> encrypt_xlsx('123.xlsx', 'password123')
>>> # try to open the Excel file and it will prompt you to enter a password.
```

Explanation of the code:

1. `w32.gencache.EnsureDispatch` launches the Excel Application.
2. `os.path.abspath` is responsible for changing the `path` to an absolute path, otherwise you might not be able to open the Excel file.
3. `xl.Workbooks.Open` opens the Excel file.
4. `xl.DisplayAlerts = False` switches off the prompts when saving to the same path.
5. `wb.SaveAs` saves the file using the original name, and 51 indicates the format of the Excel workbook. Here's the link to the Microsoft reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb241279(v=office.12)
6. `xl.Quit()` closes the Excel application. If you choose to remove this line, please remember to set the `xl.DisplayAlerts` back to `True`

If you want to open the Excel file or encrypt it with a strong password, then I would recommend you to use the ExcelHelper class which I wrote. Refer to my article in [TowardsDataScience](https://towardsdatascience.com/supercharged-pandas-encrypting-excel-files-written-from-dataframes-1251b585145b).