# Password Protecting xlsx Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, password-protection

I have been looking for this for quite some days now, there are mainly some vague approaches discussed but I could not find any solid way and in case I need to implement this, can anyone share some approach to follow?

I have checked node library which implements this https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate/blob/7480a02575c9140c0e7995623ea192c88c1886d3/lib/Encryptor.js, and it is actually working - is there anyway I can mimic this behavior in python to create a code which password protect the excel file.

I mainly want to run it on Linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password Protecting Excel file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122496/password-protecting-excel-file-using-python)

Comment: @SolarMike It does not, want approach in python - and all of the answers are either using some other approach or too vague for me to understand.

Comment: Please don't mark it as duplicate as if you don't have anything else to do, I already commented on the mentioned question and was not able to find any response - I want to find a approach solely in python, in case you have any insights please share here or in any of the "same" questions I have bookmarked them all

Comment: A python script calling vba - whats’s wrong with that? Take it and edit to suit your needs.

Comment: No it does not suit my needs, I don't want to install wine and vb on unix machine and run it to password protect a excel file.

Comment: Then add that detail to your question - does help to explain properly as then people who might have answers can help easier...