# How to password protect a excel file(xlsx) using python

Tags: python, excel

I have been looking at various websites to find a solution of password protect my excel workbook using python but I can't find anything that works.
I see couple of solutions where people have protected the file from editing but I need to password protect the entire workbook.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Here is what I have tried so far but this does not work.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

os.chdir('/Users/Documents')
test_spreadsheet = "ABC.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(test_spreadsheet)
wb.security.workbookPassword = "password"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password Protecting Excel file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122496/password-protecting-excel-file-using-python)

Comment: I tried the solution listed here but it did not work. It password protected the worksheet but not the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of password protection... you could encrypt your excel file with python. I think that is my prefered way of adding security. There are a ton of python libraries  for encryption. I have used PyCrypto and had some good luck.

Comment: How will decryption work? I have to send this file to non technical users so I have to ensure that they can open the file easily at their end.

Comment: you can send over a decryption script along with the file itself, maybe separately. The thing is... you may want to expand your stack from python because I have not been able to find anything from just python alone. or.. send a pdf instead of excel. PDFs can easily be password protected