# How make a protect from editing excel file?

Tags: python, excel, editing

I create a excel file from a dataframe:

```
#writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')    
#uniq_pros.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
#writer.save()
```

how can make it protect from editing this excell file?
i want be only for view from users...

Comment: Take a look at this question in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122496/password-protecting-excel-file-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as follows using the XlsxWriter worksheet [protect()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-protect) method:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Set protection for the worksheet.
worksheet.protect()

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

You can also add a password if required.

Answer (score 0):

"Click on the “Review” tab on the main Excel ribbon. Click “Protect Sheet.” Enter the password you would like to use to unlock the sheet in the future. Re-enter the password you made to confirm that you remember it and then click “OK." (in Excel itself)
In python you could probably encrypt it:
Here are some helpful sources:

https://blog.aspose.com/2021/06/01/encrypt-and-decrypt-excel-files-in-python/

[Password Protecting Excel file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122496/password-protecting-excel-file-using-python)

https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tutorials/python/protect-excel-sheet-cells.html